# How do you determine the size/frame of a custom UINavigationItem.titleView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

After creating a custom view and assigning it to the navigationItem.titleView property it is displayed like this

[image]

with the custom view filling the space between the two buttons. Therefore, the custom view is not centered on the navigation bar. How do I determine the frame of the view in the .titleView property? I want to center some text in the navigation bar, say under the time stamp.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you really want to get `titleView`'s frame (in your top-level view's coordinate space), you can do this:

```
[self.navBar layoutIfNeeded];
CGRect titleViewFrameInTopLevelViewSpace = [self.navigationItem.titleView
    convertRect:self.navigationItem.titleView.bounds
    toView:self.view];
```

You need to do `layoutIfNeeded` if you have just assigned `titleView`, because by default the navigation bar won't lay out its subviews until the next pass through the run loop.

**That said,** the `titleView` will be centered automatically, if it fits.  I think you are setting the frame (or bounds) of your custom view too large.  I tested this two ways:

- I set up the `titleView` directly in the XIB.  I simply dragged a View from the Object library onto the center of the navigation bar:
  [image: XIB screen shot]
  It sized the view to 128x33 automatically.  The resize handles let me adjust the size.  It stays centered until it overlaps the Categorize button.  Then it shifts left.
- I set the `titleView` property in `viewDidLoad`:

  ```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 33)];
      customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
      self.navItem.titleView = customView;
   }
  ```

  The result looks like this:
  [image: Simulator screen shot]

Comment: Thanks Rob. This is what was causing the view not to be centered.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the width of the `leftBarButtonItem` and the `rightBarButtonItem` after you've set them, and then use that to determine how to centre within the view you supply to `titleView`. That might do what you want?