# iOS nav titleView size

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, titleview

I add a `UILabel` as the `titleView` as `self.navigationItem.titleView`. The width of the label is the width of the screen and the origin is CGZero. After I add a left and right bar item the `UILabel`'s origin and width changes in relation to the screen. I have to place something directly beneath the `UILabel` with the same width however when I use `convertRect` or `convertPoint` I get the original values I have set for the frame which is incorrect relative to what is seen on screen.

What is the correct way to get the value of the `titleView`'s new frame as shown on the screen

Comment: Show some relevant code.

Comment: @rmaddy I was not exactly certain what to add as relevant code as something simple as "self.navigationItem.titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100000, height: 20))" would result in the same issue. When the UIView is added as the title view it is resized due to the left and right baritems. My question is how to get the new size relative to the screen because what will return if I simply get the screen or use convertRect is the original size

Comment: @rmaddy what I actually do is set the width and height as that of the nabber i.e  let searchBarWidth = navBar.frame.width;
            let searchBarHeight = navBar.frame.height - 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah the issue was that I was querying the size of the title view too early as the sizing of the subviews are not calculated until the next pass in the run loop I solved it in the main view as so

```
navBar.layoutIfNeeded()
var titleViewFrameInTopLevelViewSpace:CGRect = self.navigationItem.titleView!.convertRect(self.navigationItem.titleView!.bounds, toView: self.view)
println(titleViewFrameInTopLevelViewSpace)
```

Thank you @rob-mayoff

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8289028/903214